# Mean value of the image of an exponentiallly distributed time under a smooth curve

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $T$ be an exponentially distributed random variable with parameter $\lambda$
and let $\varphi\in C^1([0,\infty);\mathbb R)$.

I would like if possible to get a (nice) expression for the mean value of $\varphi_T$.

If it helps, for simplicity we can assume also $\dot\varphi_t\neq 0$ for every $t$.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 no, I don't think I want to assume this. But I forgot to write that the derivative $\dot\varphi$ is bounded (it is even periodic).

Comment: OK, then doesn't this imply that $\varphi$ is monotonic increasing, since its confined to the positive reals? You could probably get a bound on the expected value using linear functions for the max and min of $\dot \varphi$ I don't think there is a simple, general answer, as the function $\varphi$ could be quite complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T\sim E(\lambda)$

$$\mathbb E\varphi(T)=\lambda\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\varphi(t)e^{-\lambda t}dt=\lambda\mathcal L\{\varphi(t)\}$$, where $F(\lambda)=\mathcal L\{\varphi(t)\}$ is Laplace transform of the function.

As this is Laplace transform, the function must satisfy the following conditions:

1. $\varphi(t)$ is locally integrable (integrable on any finite segment of $\mathbb R^+$)
2. $\varphi(t)=0 \, \forall t<0$ (it satisfies because we don't consider negative arguments)
3. $\exists M>0,s:\,|\varphi(t)|\leq Me^{st}$

Comment: $f(t)$ should be $\phi(t)$ in 3.